# Why am I getting an "undefined" result from my MongoDBQuery in Node?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I've already stablished a DB with it's schema like this:
[image]

When I use my search function in Nodejs it works perfectly and returns my info like this:\

[image]

So, why is is than when I try to fectch my user from mongodb and get the parameter "examenes":
[image]

I get this undefined return?:
[image]

Comment: I think you forgot to use `await`.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you are not using `await` so in the line `console.log(user.examenes)` the variable `user` is not the data returned by mongo; is another object without attribute `examenes`. And trying to access the value is `undefined`.

So you can use:

```
let user = await (usuario.findOne({_id: req.params.id}))
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you added `mergeParams` in your router?
This options adds params object to the request
`const router = express.Router({ mergeParams: true });`

then
`/predict/:id` results in `req.params.id`

*By default this option is disabled in express*

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the `await` keyword

```
try{
   var user = await model.findOne({ _id: req.params.id});
} catch (e) {
   // Handle Errors
};
```

Or

```
model.findOne({ _id: req.params.id}).then(result => {
  var user = result;
}).catch(e=> {
// Handle Errors
});
```